# Unexpected keyword argument in matplotlib

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

The following is my code which uploads a csv file with 11 columns and 2891 rows. Some column name include "TCA", "MONTH", "NORM_OIL_1KFT". Once I try to plot months against norm oil I get an unexpected keyword argument

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

filepath =  r"C:\Users\jrivera\Documents\Python\maverickAvgTCProductionInput.csv"

def read_csv(filepath):
    df = pd.read_csv(filepath, header = 0)
    return df

dfHDprd = read_csv(filepath)

print(dfHDprd)

api = "Del_10_WC_A2"

dcaPRD = dfHDprd[dfHDprd["TCA"] == api]

fig = plt.plot(dcaPRD, x = "MONTH", y = "NORM_OIL_1KFT", kind = 'scatter')
fig.show()

Error:
runfile('C:/Users/jrivera/Documents/Python/DCAJorge2.py', wdir='C:/Users/jrivera/Documents/Python')
               TCA MAV_TYPE_CURVE  ... NORM_GAS_1KFT_CUM    WEIGHT
0     Del_10_WC_A2         Del_10  ...            6,547   1.000000
1     Del_10_WC_A2         Del_10  ...           10,966   1.000000
2     Del_10_WC_A2         Del_10  ...           15,288   1.000000
3     Del_10_WC_A2         Del_10  ...           18,982   1.000000
4     Del_10_WC_A2         Del_10  ...           22,483   1.000000
           ...            ...  ...               ...       ...
2886    Mid_4_WC_D          Mid_4  ...           69,977   0.111111
2887    Mid_4_WC_D          Mid_4  ...           70,910   0.111111
2888    Mid_4_WC_D          Mid_4  ...           72,015   0.111111
2889    Mid_4_WC_D          Mid_4  ...           73,005   0.111111
2890    Mid_4_WC_D          Mid_4  ...           73,661   0.111111

[2891 rows x 11 columns]
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\jrivera\Documents\Python\DCAJorge2.py", line 22, in <module>
    fig = plt.plot(dcaPRD, x = "MONTH", y = "NORM_OIL_1KFT")

  File "C:\Users\jrivera\AppData\Local\Programs\Spyder\pkgs\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 3021, in plot
    **({"data": data} if data is not None else {}), **kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\jrivera\AppData\Local\Programs\Spyder\pkgs\matplotlib\axes\_axes.py", line 1605, in plot
    lines = [*self._get_lines(*args, data=data, **kwargs)]

  File "C:\Users\jrivera\AppData\Local\Programs\Spyder\pkgs\matplotlib\axes\_base.py", line 251, in __call__
    .format(self.command, pos_only))

TypeError: plot got an unexpected keyword argument 'x'
```

I don't know how to pass the xvalue and yvalue to keyword x and y. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It should be `dcaPRD.plot(x="MONTH", y="NORM_OIL_1KFT", kind='scatter')` since you are plotting the dataframe. See [`pandas.DataFrame.plot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html). I'm voting to close this as a caused by a typo/not reproducible.

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing seaborn's parameters with [that of matplotlib's scatter](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.scatter.html). Just do `plt.scatter(dcaPRD['MONTH'], dcaPRD['NORM_OIL_1KFT'])`